# Using a cronjob on node for storing a json file, parsing it and update a database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to retrieve a file from a website every minute that contains boats location.

Then, I parse the file, delete all the boats from my database and re-create all of them at the new position indicated in the file.

Here's my code so far - in the *server.js* of my loopbackjs app:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var reload = require('require-reload')(require);
var app = module.exports = loopback();

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.(loopbackjs mandatory code)
boot(app, __dirname, function (err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;

    var Boat = app.models.Boat;
    var ais_url_france = 'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=XXXXXXXXX&format=1&output=json&compress=0&latmin=40&latmax=52&lonmin=-5&lonmax=10';

    //start the cronjob on a node env every min
    new CronJob('* * * * *', function () {
                // get the file and save as a .json
                exec('wget "' + ais_url_france + '" -O aishub_france.json', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                    // I need to use reload here because the file is stored in memory otherwise and only read once after the first download...
                    var file = reload('../aishub_france.json');
                    if (file[0].ERROR === false) {
                        var boats = file[1];
                        if (boats.length > 0) {
                            Boat.destroyAll({typeId: 'aishub_boats'}, function (err, info) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < boats.length; i++) {
                                    Boat.create({
                                        name: boats[i].NAME,
                                        latlng: {
                                            lat: boats[i].LATITUDE,
                                            lng: boats[i].LONGITUDE
                                        },
                                        typeId: 'aishub_boats'
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }, null, true, null);
});
```

I'm not sure the code here is so great but here are my troubles:

- The downloaded file is huge (1,3Mo)
- I need to remove and re-add all the boats because they change location and some might appear/disappear (maybe there is a better solution)
- Not sure using **require-reload** is the best solution, but if I don't the file is read only once in the cronjob even if the donwloaded file changed each time...
- I think I might have some memory leak because I'm having strange stacks trace recently after I added this code. Here is the trace:

  `33503717 ms: Mark-sweep 1288.0 (1403.6) -> 1288.0 (1404.6) MB, 672.5 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].`

  `33504750 ms: Mark-sweep 1288.0 (1404.6) -> 1288.0 (1404.6) MB, 847.3 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].`

  `33505597 ms: Mark-sweep 1288.0 (1404.6) -> 1288.0 (1403.6) MB, 846.4 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].`

  `33506438 ms: Mark-sweep 1288.0 (1403.6) -> 1288.0 (1403.6) MB, 841.4 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].`

Comment: Are you using any sort of compression for the file download? Secondly, does the file need to be written to disk? Could you stream from the remote location instead and handle directly in memory? Those are areas I’d be looking at.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to make this changes tomorrow and tell you if it runs smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thank you James!

I was able to get rid of **require-reload** using **request**, and use the compression with **adm-zip** on the fly:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var request = require('request');
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');

var ais_url_france = 'http://data.aishub.net/ws.php?username=XXX&format=1&output=json&compress=1&latmin=40&latmax=52&lonmin=-5&lonmax=10';
new CronJob('* * * * *', function () {
     request({url: ais_url_france, encoding: null}, function (error, response, data) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var zip = new AdmZip(data);
                var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
                if (zipEntries && zipEntries.length) {
                    var file = JSON.parse(zip.readAsText(zipEntries[0]));
                    if (file[0].ERROR === false) {
                        var boats = file[1];
                        if (boats.length > 0) {
                            Boat.destroyAll(function (err, info) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < boats.length; i++) {
                                    Boat.create({
                                        name: boats[i].NAME,
                                        latlng: {
                                            lat: boats[i].LATITUDE,
                                            lng: boats[i].LONGITUDE
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }, null, true, null);
```

Comment: Glad to hear you’ve made some progress, so I’m noticing you are passing `compress=0` to the API - this definitely isn’t a flag to determine whether the response should be compressed?

Comment: Yes it is. But I wasn't able to manage the .gzip in memory after that. Too bad, but at least the memory leak is gone!

Comment: In what sense? If you’re happy with what you now have then no worries but with a 1.3Mb download that’s still gona have a significant latency problem (depending on your download speed & upload speed of the target server). Compression might add extra latency too though so it’s about weighing up the pros / cons.

Comment: You are right, I'll definitely check this problem again - but the most important part is solved - thank to you! The .gzip file is 315ko. If I get some times soon, I'll update my post here of what causes me troubles.

Comment: That's approx a 10th of the size of the original file download - sounds like it'd be worth the time to sort.

Comment: Updated! Finally! Thank you for pushing me through my limits ;)